# while call python script from php. how to run python script in background (Asynchronous)

Tags: php, python, linux, ubuntu

I am using ubuntu . i run python script from php function.I want to run the python in background (Asynchronous) . I try following codes. the codes are working but the  control is waiting for full python script to completed. After that only moves to next line in php file.

```
shell_exec("nohup python2.7 /var/www/html/pythonproject/python.py /var/www/html/file 100525 &");

exec("nohup /usr/bin/python2.7 /var/www/html/pythonproject/python.py /var/www/html/file 100525 &");
```

**I Found Solution**
it is working for me

```
exec("/usr/bin/python2.7 /var/www/html/pythonproject/python.py /var/www/html/file 100525  > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &")
```

Comment: exec("/usr/bin/python2.7 /var/www/html/pythonproject/python.py /var/www/html/file 100525  > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &")

Answer (score 2):

You should fork() a child process and then wait() for it.
In PHP I believe you fork using this:
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php